# How to generate random numbers for multiple rows in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to generate random values for multiple rows in a column. The random values need to be in the range of 0.005 and 0.015 inclusive.

I have tried using the abs(checksum(newID()) but I am not sure how to specify a range using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rand()` and arithmetic:

```
select rand(checksum(newID())) * 0.01 + 0.005
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a range like this by using the RAND() function.

Please execute SQL and you can see. The number that comes will be within the range.

**SQL:**

```
SELECT RAND()*(0.015-0.005)+0.005 as randomNumber
```

**Here,** 0.015 and 0.005 are range number.

**SQL output**

```
|----|-------|----------------------|
|id  |empCode| randomNumber         |
|----|------------------------------|
|1   | 0001  | 0.01245219297469798  |
|----|-------|----------------------|
|2   | 0002  | 0.010188965811570142 |
|----|-------|----------------------|
```

Hopefully, your problem will be resolved.

Comment: This will generate the same random number for every row. Not what I am looking for.

Comment: @Franktank24 I have executed SQL Query and a unique number is generated for each line from the query.

Comment: @Franktank24 I have added the output of the SQL query in the above answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game... but here's a good solution:
Random number in range.

```
ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%<Number of Values in Range> + <Lowest Value in Range> + 1
```

So here we get a RandomNumber for each row with values between 10 and 20

```
SELECT FirstName,MiddleName,LastName, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%10 + 11 AS RandomNumber
FROM Person.Person
```

Taken from
https://sqlundercover.com/2017/06/22/generating-random-numbers-for-each-row-over-a-specified-range-and-other-funky-stuff-you-can-do-with-them/